# RegularExpression validator so my textbox have to start with uppercase

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using this expression:

> ^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$

And it works fine if I type for example "Kristian". But when I want to continue that sentence like typing "Kristian is working with SharePoint", it doesn't work. Any better expression out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
[A-Z].*
```

For reference, `^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$` is making sure each word's first letter is capitalized and is not matching "every character" that could occur.

Check out http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm for good reference material.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Non-REGEX solution. You can use [char.IsUpper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.isupper.aspx) on the first character of your string to see if it starts with upper case.

```
if(textbox.Text.Length > 0 && char.IsUpper(textBox.Text[0]))
{
  //starts with upper case
}
```

or use [Char.IsUpper Method (String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2bxftt7.aspx)

```
if(textbox.Text.Length > 0 && char.IsUpper(textBox.Text,0))
{
  //starts with upper case
}
```

Comment: @Kriistiian, sure. REGEX would be an overkill for something this trivial

Comment: @Habib, I understand, but right now I got like 100 textboxes, and need to check everyone so the first letter is uppercase, this will be to long code.. I'll try the expression that Izzy provides with

Comment: Extract that logic in a function, Pass that function your text and you will get the result. You can use that with every textbox in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Regex:

> "\b(\w|['-])+\b"

You could also use other framework methods:

```
string capitalized = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("capitalize this string");
```